# Filter pandas columns to get desired value counts

Tags: python, pandas, filter

Lets say I have dataframe with columns 'A' and 'B', if I do value_counts() for these two columns I get the following:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 39 |
| 10 | 98 |
| 15 | 79 |
| 20 | 40 |
| 25 | 29 |
| 30 | 17 |
| 35 | 8 |

|  | B |
| --- | --- |
| -30 | 7 |
| -20 | 15 |
| -10 | 57 |
| -0 | 138 |
| 10 | 60 |
| 20 | 26 |
| 30 | 7 |

Is there a way to filter this dataframe such that the the filtered dataframe value_counts() yields desired counts for both A and B?

say the desired value_counts() for A and B are as follow:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 10 | 7 |
| 15 | 13 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 25 | 15 |
| 30 | 8 |
| 35 | 8 |

|  | B |
| --- | --- |
| -30 | 3 |
| -20 | 6 |
| -10 | 16 |
| -0 | **25** |
| 10 | 7 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 30 | 2 |

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it's generally possible if you want one sample with desired distribution for both A and B. For example, if B==30 always go with A==30, then the 8 rows with A==30  in the sample implies all 7 B==30 rows in the original data.

Comment: Not without using optimization and constraints. You'd need to use another package for that. Your answer could yield many solutions. For that I'd look into a constraint logic programming (CLP) solver.

Comment: fair point Quang! I would have to relax the target distribution for both A and B, i.e. give it some wiggle room. In which case Stu's approach, using optimization, makes sense! thank you both!

Comment: You have a total of 63 desired counts for A, but 64 desired counts for B.

Comment: @MichaelCao: thanks for pointing this out! I made the correction. Desired total counts for both A and B now add up to 63

Answer (score 0):

I can only propose a set-up, but I've yet to find a good implementation. The idea is to turn each row into a vector that represents which index the unique value is at.

For example, if the first row has A = 10 which is the second unique value in A and B= -30 which is the first unique value in B, we can turn that into the vector:

`[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

where we have a 1 on the second index in the first seven slots and a 1 on the first index in the second seven slots.

If we do this for all rows and get a matrix M, we can formulate our filtering problem as `M.T @ filter = target_counts_vec`.

The remaining problem is to constrain the filter to 0's and 1's which we can do with something like a Heaviside function. The problem is the solver itself because we are solving a non-square matrix.

Here's the setup so far, but with nothing for the final solve:

```
# Set up problem and solution
values = {
    "A": [5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25],
    "B": [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-10,-10,-15,-15,-15,-15,-20,-20,-25,-25,-30,-30,-30,-30,-35,],
}

# Solution to check
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, 20, dtype = bool)

df = pd.DataFrame(values)

A_target = df.loc[mask, 'A'].value_counts()
B_target = df.loc[mask, 'B'].value_counts()

A_u, A_ind = np.unique(df['A'], return_inverse = True)
A_vec = [[0 if i != j else 1 for j in range(max(A_ind)+1)] for i in A_ind]

B_u, B_ind = np.unique(df['B'], return_inverse = True)
B_vec = [[0 if i != j else 1 for j in range(max(B_ind)+1)] for i in B_ind]

M = np.array([A + B for A,B in zip(A_vec, B_vec)])

A_target = pd.DataFrame(index = A_u).join(A_target).fillna(0).astype(int)
B_target = pd.DataFrame(index = B_u).join(B_target).fillna(0).astype(int)

target_vec = list(A_target['A']) + list(B_target['B'])

# Need to solve M.T @ filter = target_vec
```